# Highlight cell data in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, datatables, compatibility

I'm trying to highlight data in green that is showing positive growth or vice versa.
But i'm facing some issues in Chrome browser while it works fine in Firefox.

Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ordering": false,
   "columnDefs": [
    {
    "targets": 4,
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col)  
    {
    if ( cellData.contains("-")) // works fine for Firefox but not for Chrome 
    $(td).css('color', 'red') 
    else $(td).css('color', 'green')
    }
    },
    {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) 
            { return data +' ('+ Math.round(row[4]*10)/10+'%)'; },"targets": 3
    }
    ]

  });

  } );
  </script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>     

  <!-- DataTables CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <!-- DataTables -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

   <!--DATATABLES-->

   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


     <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Metrics</th>
            <th>Till Now</th>
            <th>Today Trending</th>
            <th>Yesterday</th>
            <th>DY</th>
            <th>5 Day Average</th>
            <th>Same Time Last <?php echo date("l");?></th>
            <th>Highest</th>
            <th>Lowest</th>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Run Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Metrics</th>
            <th>Till Now</th>
            <th>Today Trending</th>
            <th>Yesterday</th>
            <th>DY</th>
            <th>5 Day Average</th>
            <th>Same Time Last <?php echo date("l");?></th>
            <th>Highest</th>
            <th>Lowest</th>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Run Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
    <?php

      while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.'<strong>'.$row['metric'].'</strong>'.'</td>';

    //Till Now

      echo '<td>'.number_format($row['Till_Now'], 2, '.', '').'</td>';

       //Trending
       echo '<td>'.number_format($row['Trending'], 2, '.', '').'</td>'; 
      //Yesterday
      echo '<td>'.number_format($row['Yesterday'],2,'.','').'</td>';                            

       //Diff
    echo '<td>'.($row['Trending']-$row['Yesterday'])*100/$row['Yesterday'].'</td>'; 


    //5_days_avg

      echo '<td>'.number_format($row['5_days_avg'],2,'.','').'</td>';               

     //STLW

      echo '<td>'.number_format($row['stlw'],2,'.','').'</td>'; 
      ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: another alternative i tried was :

    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col)  
    {
    if ( cellData.contains("-")) 
    $(td).css('color', 'red') 
    else $(td).css('color', 'green')
    }

Works fine for Firefox but throws error for chrome.

Comment: I know it's not the subject here but how can this work while you are calling $ before loading jquery and not closing your php while loop with a curly brace ?

Comment: this code is just the snippet so '}' is not visible here and even if i load my jquery before the script it isnt working. clearly it is a compatibility issue i need an alternative to createdCell callback function. Please help.

Comment: It works fine when im trying to execute createdCell and render function separately but not when used together in Chrome.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` some elements like `cellData` or `td` in order to see if they are correctly set in chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, hope it helps :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
    "ordering": false,

   "columnDefs": [

    //Shortening data cell
    {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) 
            { return data +' ('+ Math.round(row[4]*10)/10+'%)'; },"targets": 3
    },
    //Hide column
    { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 4 ] },

    //Highlighting data

    {

    "targets": [3],
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
          if ( cellData.indexOf("-")==-1) 
              $(td).css('color', 'green')
          else $(td).css('color', 'red')                     }
    }
]

});
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

you will need to edit the css and program it for chrome. have you tried it?
edit: try double quote marks " where the colors go.

Comment: how do i program it for chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This code syntax usually works in Google Chrome:

```
$('.status:contains("Paid")').css('color', 'red');
$('.status:contains("Received")').css('color', 'green');
```